# How to read a file .txt

Tags: python

I am a very beginner in Python and I am trying to become more confident opening .txt and .csv files. As exercise, I am trying to open a file named "Trissino.txt", where is contained some lines of a poetry. So I typed:

```py
file = open ("Trissino.txt", "r")
lettura = file.readlines()

print(type(lettura))

for x in lettura:
    print(x)
```

and I obtained the whole text of the poetry as output. Then, as output, I would like to obtain all the lines in which the word "sinistra" is contained in the poetry, so I typed:

```py
if "sinistra" in x:
    print(x)
```

I also tried:

```py
if x == "sinistra":
   print(x)
```

but nothing happened. I am sure that the word "sinistra" can be found in many lines because I read the text some month ago. I am surely doing eveything wrong but I don´t find any hint for textual research with Python on the web. How can i go further? Do I need other tools to do this search? Every tipp is relly welcome!

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking 'sinistra' outside the loop, you must check while you are traversing each line from the text file.

```
file = open ("Trissino.txt", "r")
lettura = file.readlines()

print(type(lettura))

for x in lettura:
    if 'sinistra' in x:
        prin(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an approach using regex

```
import re
file = open ("Trissino.txt", "r")
lettura = file.readlines()

for verso in lettura: # read the already acquired data line by line
 if None != re.match("sinistra", verso): # if the pattern sinistra is contained into the line
  print(verso) #it prints the line
 if None != re.match("^sinistra",verso):
  print ("verso begins with word sinistra")
 if None != != re.match("sinistra$",verso):
  print ("verso ends with word sinistra")
```

this exemplum assumes no punctuation is present and that all the text is lowercase, it can be easly modified to became case-insensitive and to handle the punctuation